# Convert Hex value to Date

Tags: date, decoding, binary-data

I have an RAF (Random Access File) from a VB6 application (without source) that I'm trying to read, but I can't figure out the format of the date in the file. Maybe you have seen something like this? Here are some sample values (The hex values on the right is what I see in the data file after using the date on the left in the VB6 application):

```
01/01/1900 - 00 00 00 00 40
01/02/1900 - 00 00 00 08 40
01/03/1900 - 00 00 00 10 40
01/04/1900 - 00 00 00 14 40

01/01/1900 - 00 00 00 00 40
02/01/1900 - 00 00 80 40 40
03/01/1900 - 00 00 80 4e 40
04/01/1900 - 00 00 00 57 40
05/01/1900 - 00 00 80 5e 40

12/31/1900 - 00 00 e0 76 40

10/10/1901 - 00 00 f0 76 40
10/20/1901 - 00 00 00 77 40
10/30/1901 - 00 00 10 77 40

10/10/1902 - 00 00 e0 86 40
10/20/1902 - 00 00 e8 86 40
10/30/1902 - 00 00 f0 86 40

10/10/1950 - 00 00 d6 d1 40
10/20/1950 - 00 40 d6 d1 40
10/30/1950 - 00 80 d6 d1 40

10/10/1951 - 00 80 c2 d5 40

10/02/2023 - 00 20 12 e6 40

10/10/2100 - 00 b0 d5 f1 40
```

I tried to find a pattern in the values to correspond to days/hours/minutes/seconds etc. The base line is 1/1/1970, but the values after this doesn't add up with any regular pattern. It's not BCD coded. I tried to split up the bytes, but didn't make any sense. I tried to look at individual coded days, months and years, but didn't add up.

Comment: How do you have dates like `40/01/1900` or `50/01/1900` in your application? Those can't be valid dates.

Comment: It's also very likely that the bytes you're showing here aren't the ones related to the date at all.  How are you determining which bytes to show us?

Comment: That will be difficult as there is no linear progress between the first four example values.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint The numbers were just updated wrong when I copied over from my notepad. I have updated them correctly now.

Comment: @Gustav Yes, there is no linear progress that I can see, that is why I'm asking for help :-)

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I did a diff on the RAF file before and after changing the date. These are the only bytes that are changing. I can also change these same bytes in the file and the date will be updated in the application. I'm pretty sure these are the correct bytes.

Comment: Your showing us 5 bytes, the first and last which are fixed.  It's unclear the alignment of the bytes, so it's entirely possible the leading `00` or the trailing `40` belong to some other piece of data.  Also it's possible that the file is compressed or encrypted in some manner, in which case it will be nearly impossible to answer this question.  Can you provide any more details about what program is creating the file, or perhaps provide a link to an entire file?

Comment: It's also possible that when you save the file, the program is also saving some other piece of data blended with this one - such as the current time, or incrementing some counter, or a computed checksum, etc.  The possibilities are endless.